# React Native Android App crashes when importing axios

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, axios

My React Native Android App works fine, but as soon as I import 'axios' I get an error:

```
The development server returned response error code: 500

Body:
{"type":"InternalError","errors":[],"message":"Metro Bundler has encountered an internal error, please check your terminal error output for more details"}
processBundleResult
    BundleDownloader.java:266
access$200
    BundleDownloader.java:35
onResponse
    BundleDownloader.java:153
execute
    RealCall.java:135
run
    NamedRunnable.java:32
runWorker
    ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113
run
    ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588
run
    Thread.java:818
```

I'm using Nexus 4 emulator with Marshmallow 6.0
This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

class AlbumList extends Component {


  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Album List</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default AlbumList;
```

The error happens sad when I include line 3.

Comment: can you please add code to your question? so we can see what you have tried so far.

Comment: Reboot your server or kill the sesione of node:
"ps aux | grep node"
select the correct Pid and kill it